# what's the more effecient way to read a text file

Tags: python, performance, io

There's text file(about 300M) and need to count the top N frequency words. The first step is to read it from disk, now I simply use `open.read().lower()`(case insensitive) is there a more effecient way to handle the IO part? Test machine has 8 cores 4G memory and Linux system, python version is 2.6.

Comment: How fast do you need it to be? You can get a baseline which factors IO and word splitting out nicely `time wc -w m30text.txt` → 0.67s wallclock. Martijn's answer on the same 30M word (34MB on disk) text file: 3.0s. The Python GIL will likely keep you from reducing the 2.3s to populate the Counter object no matter how many cores you have.

Comment: thanks maybe python is not an approporiate language for this kind of question

Comment: That wasn't the intended conclusion at all. You've got a lower bound on how fast a file can be read and parsed into words. If you've measured an alternate implementation that is correct, bug free, and more performant then show us. Until you've measured it, it doesn't exist and most people's intuitions about the performance of Python intrinsics are usually incorrect.

Comment: @msw my test file is about 20M, the best java time to get the answer is about 350ms, the best C++ time is about 170ms.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, process the file line by line in an iterator:

```
with open(filename) as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        line = line.lower()
```

This uses a buffer for read performance but does not put as much pressure on your memory, avoiding having to swap.

Next, use [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do the frequency counting for you. It'll handle the counting and selecting the top N words for you, in the most efficient manner available in pure Python code.

A naive way to get words would be to split the lines on whitespace; combining that with a generator expression could give you all the word counts in one line of code:

```
from collections import Counter

with open(filename) as inputfile:
    counts = Counter(word for line in inputfile for word in line.lower().split())

for word, frequency in counts.most_common(N):
    print '{<40} {}'.format(word, frequency)
```

The `Counter` class was added in Python 2.7; for 2.6 you can use [this backport](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/).

Comment: thanks, is reading line by line only make sense when the memory can't load all the data? Does the Counter() use a multi thread module to do the frequency word counting job?

Comment: No, `Counter()` does not use any multi-process or threading tricks. You'd have to do that yourself, then re-combine the results. `Counter()` objects can readily be summed.

Comment: Counter() is faster then heap I used before, I'll try multi process, thanks